# Рисование в MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Как используя функции MATLAB нарисовать линию между двумя точками с   координатами (x1,y1) и (x2,y2) соответственно?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [x1 x2];
y = [y1 y2];
line(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте plot

```
x = [x1, x2];
y = [y1, y2];
plot(x, y)
```